# sagemaker studio/step functions ContextualVersionConflic in urllib3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I'm trying to run a notebook that uses stepfunctions in a sagemaker studio notebook(with Data Science 3.0 image and python 3 kernel), however the notebook fails in the first cell(imports) in `import stepfunctions` with the error:

```
ContextualVersionConflict: (urllib3 2.0.4 (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages), 
Requirement.parse('urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4'), {'botocore'})
```

The stepfunctions package is installed before that cell using:

```
!pip install stepfunctions
```

Given that the error shows urllib range, I initially thought the error is related to urllib version and a version change should fix it, however when trying to install version 1.26.17 it says the requeriment is satisfied, and if I print urllib version indeed it shows 1.26.17. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried a different kernel image? Have you tried installing from source: https://github.com/aws/aws-step-functions-data-science-sdk-python#installing-the-aws-step-functions-data-science-sdk